# How to pause the invocation of one function until another function is invoked independently?

Tags: javascript, promise, callback

I have working code below, but I feel like there must be a cleaner solution and I don't think that promise or callback will work in my case.

I have one master function (foo) that independently calls itself after x milliseconds (in my actual code, it does this repeatedly). When it does call itself, it increments a value stored in an object.

I have a second function (bar) that gets randomly called on occasion. However, I'd like (in some cases) to be able to pause the execution of this function until the next time the master function (foo) is called again.

In my working example below,  `bar` stores the current value of `prop` when `bar` is invoked, and then keeps checking the value of `prop` repeatedly until the value changes. When the values are no longer ==, `bar` executes the code in `else`. This works but isn't clean and the timing isn't as accurate as it could be if `bar` simply listened for `prop` to change (or `foo` to be invoked), and was executed at that moment.

I don't believe that promise or callback will work because they are usually used in cases where a second function is passed as an argument. In my case, my second function is one that has another job and is doing its own job repeatedly already. I also don't want the second function to be executed again, I just want its invocation to allow function one to complete its own execution.

Using a delay is also not ideal for my actual case.

**Further Details**

My actual program makes music by randomly triggering audio files to play. `bar()` is the function that determines all the ways/properties by which a sound is played (duration, volume, fade-in/out, etc.).

`foo()` is a master function that determines what part of the song the program is in. So every time `foo()` is called, it increments which stage the program/song is in (i.e., 1, 2, 3, 4) and it also calls a number of functions, updating properties, that change how the `get()` functions are allowed to play the sounds.

So, the program primarily plays sounds randomly (like not on rigid beat/bars) and I want the option of being able to play them on the bars in some cases. Since `foo()` is the function that is keeping track of this timing, I have added functionality to `get()` so that when a sound is not triggered on a beat, it delays until the assigned beat happens and then is allowed to play. I have that functionality working.

The trick comes in when a sound has been assigned to fall on a beat that has already passed. In these cases, I need to pause `get()` until the next bar (i.e., when `foo()` is called again). In normal music cases, the time (Beats Per Minute) would be fixed so that I could simply do the math and have it setTimeout until the correct time. But, my program is a little nontraditional and the duration changes every time that `foo()` is invoked. So the duration of the next bar isn’t known ahead of time.

So, to summarize, `bar()` (the sound) gets invoked with a whole bunch of parameters that it has stored that determine how a sound will play. And I need `bar()` to pause after it has been invoked until it hears/sees that `foo()` has been invoked again and only then completes its job of playing the sound.

Here is my working example.

```js
const config = {
  object: {
    prop: 1
  },
};

(function foo() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    config.object.prop = 3;
    console.log('foo changed the value of config.object.prop');
  }, 4000);
})();

bar();

function bar() {

  var prop = config.object.prop;

  (function nar() {
    if (prop == config.object.prop) {
      console.log('sorry, still waiting for config.object.prop to change');
      setTimeout(function() {
        nar();
      }, 1000);
    } else {
      console.log('Executed only after config.object.prop changed!!!');
    }
  })();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a perfect use case for callbacks and the observer pattern.

Your master process should produce beat events, and trigger functions that are waiting for them.

You can use a framework for message busses that helps you with this, or you could even use a function that gets a promise for the next beat to occur from the master process, but a homegrown solution can work as well. All you need is an array of listener functions, `bar` adding the on-beat part of the functionality to that list and `foo` calling (and removing) the functions from that list.

Comment: It sounds like you are suggesting that I need to restructure my approach. I currently have independent functions that trigger the sounds (and I’d like to keep it this way if possible). You’re suggesting that I must have the master function do all the triggering, no? Is my approach not possible?

Comment: Also, The observer pattern is boggling my mind a bit. When the subject notifies the subscribed observers, can it also return something (a value?) that can cause the observer function to finally finish and trigger the sample play? I suspect this is why you were suggesting that I pair the observer with a callback. But if that’s the case, I’m not sure that I’d need the observer pattern at all. I have the feeling that what I’m asking is senseless, but maybe you can straighten me out. Thanks

Comment: You should keep your independent functions for the individual sounds. But instead of somehow "waiting" for the master function bars, especially by polling a flag, you should use the observer pattern or some similar form of messaging. The master function doesn't know *what* it triggers, only *when* it does - anything can subscribe.

Comment: No, in the traditional observer pattern the subscribers do not return anything, they are void functions. I'm not sure what you mean by "cause the observer function to finally finish". However, if returning the sound to be played makes it easier for your, you may deviate from the tradition.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a Boolean to decide if nar() should be called each time that foo() is executed and have bar() set the Boolean to true when the function needs to run.

```js
let runNar = false;

(function foo() {
  setTimeout(function() {
 if (runNar === true) {
  nar();
  runNar = false;
 }
    console.log('foo changed the value of config.object.prop');
  }, 4000);
})();

bar();

function bar() {
 runNar = true;
};

function nar() {
 console.log('Excuted when foo() is called');
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be solved using Promises too, but I think there are better solutions:
Using [`setter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set)s or the [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy)!

#### How does it work?

- **Setter:**
  The setters can define pseudo-properties,  which can't have a value, but if you try to set the value of that property, a function will be called, receiving the new value as argument.

**Syntax:**

```js
var obj={
  prop:1,
  set anotherProp(value){
    //Handle set:
    this.prop=value
  }
}
obj.anotherProp=5
obj.prop //5
```

**Translated to your case:**

```js
const config = {
  object: {
    prop: 1,
    set setterProp(value){
      this.prop=value;
      bar()
    }
  },
};

(function foo() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('foo changed the value of config.object.prop');
    config.object.setterProp = 3;
  }, 4000);
})();

function bar() {
    console.log('Executed only after config.object.prop changed!!!');
}
```

- **Proxy:**
  With the Proxy objects, you can do things like setters, but:

  1. The Proxy can be used to monitor & control any action to the object (get, set, delete, function call, class construct, etc.)
  2. Unlike setters, Proxy monitors an object's all properties.

**Syntax:**

```js
var obj={
  prop:1
}
var proxy=new Proxy(obj,{
  set:function(obj,prop,value){
    //Handle set:
    obj[prop]=value;
  }
})
proxy.prop=5
proxy.prop //5
obj.prop   //5
```

**Translated to your case:**

```js
const config = {
  object: {
    prop: 1
  },
};
const proxy=new Proxy(config.object, {
  set: function(obj,prop,value){
    //Handle set:
    obj[prop]=value;
    if(prop==='prop'){bar()};
  }
});
(function foo() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('foo changed the value of config.object.prop');
    proxy.prop = 3;
  }, 4000);
})();

function bar(){
  console.log('Executed only after config.object.prop changed!!!');
}
```

#### Ok, but what if I don't want to call bar everytime!

```js
const barList=[]
const config = {
  object: {
    prop: 1
  },
};
const proxy=new Proxy(config.object, {
  set: function(obj,prop,value){
    //Handle set:
    obj[prop]=value;
    if(prop==='prop'){
      barList.filter(x=>{
        bar(...x)
        return false
      })
    };
  }
});
(function foo() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('foo changed the value of config.object.prop');
    proxy.prop = 3;
  }, 4000);
})();
function callBar(...args){
  barList.push(args)
}
function bar(...argument){
  console.log('Executed only after config.object.prop changed!!!', ...argument);
}
callBar();
callBar('with','some','arguments');
```

Comment: Thank you for this very thorough answer. I think I now understand getters and setters. Proxy is still boggling my mind. If I understand your ideas correctly, there is one aspect that doesn't suit my needs. It seems like you are giving the control of invoking bar() to foo(). I don't think that works in my case because I will already have invoked get() earlier. I need get() to be the function in control of listening in to when foo() gets called so that after get() has already been invoked, when foo() does its thing, only then can get() simply finish what it was doing.

Comment: @forestkelley Sorry, I couldn't understood your case completely... What is `get()`, and what does it do?

Comment: No problem @FZs I have still learned quite a bit. I meant to write `bar()` instead of `get()` in that last post. Sorry! I will update it if SO will allow me to edit. To answer your question, I’ve added more explanation of the program and my needs in the “Further Details” section of my question above. Thanks!

Comment: Nothing in here needs a proxy.